# Modeling out an array with nested objects and keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, dictionary

I have been looking around to find out how to model out the array below. I access this array by `tide.tideSummary` - I have tried examples on its own modeling a basic dictionary with 1 level of data, but this has nested data. I was looking into JSONModel which seems great but I dont think it can dive in to nested dictionaries?

I know how to grab a single object say `data` and get `pretty` - but I want to display several pieces and am trying to display them by: (I would have each declared in my header file).

`self.date.pretty`
`self.data.type`, etc

Thoughts on doing this? I think it would be overkill to loop through each item and add to a new object, seems like too much work and processing to do what I need to do.

```
    "tideSummary": [
        {
            "date": {
                "pretty": "11:58 AM PST on December 19, 2013",
                ........

            },
            "utcdate": {
                "pretty": "7:58 PM GMT on December 19, 2013",
                ........
            },
            "data": {
                "height": "5.97 ft",
                "type": "High Tide"
            }
        },
        ........,
        ........,
```

---

***This is my current solution as of now:***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    NSDictionary *eachTideSummary = [TideModel tideSingleton].tideSummary[indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary *dataDic = [eachTideSummary objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSDictionary *dateDic = [eachTideSummary objectForKey:@"date"];

    NSLog(@"Pretty date: %@", [dateDic objectForKey:@"pretty"]);
    NSLog(@"Data type: %@", [dataDic objectForKey:@"type"]);


    cell.textLabel.text = [dataDic objectForKey:@"type"];

    return cell;
}
```

Would love to hear any ideas or pointers? thanks

Comment: You can use [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) (after extracting the object you need for the cell): `[eachTideSummary valueForKeyPath:@"data.height"]`

Comment: @DanShelly Thanks, performance/best practice was that is "acceptable" to do. My current solution is doing something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Mantle Framework](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle) by github. It's easy to use and quite powerfull.

update:

```
#import <Specta.h>
#import <Expecta.h>
#import <Mantle.h>

#pragma mark GIInterfaces

@interface GIDate : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pretty;
@end

@interface GIUtcDate : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pretty;
@end

@interface GIData : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *height;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@end

@interface GITide : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) GIDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GIUtcDate *utcDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GIData *data;
@end

@interface GITideSummary : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tides;
@end

#pragma mark - GIImplementation

@implementation GIDate

+ (NSDictionary*)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey{
    return @{@"pretty": @"pretty"};
}

@end

@implementation GIUtcDate

+ (NSDictionary*)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey{
    return @{@"pretty": @"pretty"};
}

@end

@implementation GIData

+ (NSDictionary*)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey{
    return @{@"height": @"height",
             @"type" : @"type"};
}

@end

@implementation GITide

+ (NSDictionary*)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey{
    return @{@"date": @"date",
             @"utcDate" : @"utcdate",
             @"data": @"data"};
}

+ (NSValueTransformer*)dateJSONTransformer{
    return [MTLValueTransformer mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:[GIDate class]];
}

+ (NSValueTransformer*)utcDateJSONTransformer{
    return [MTLValueTransformer mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:[GIUtcDate class]];
}

+ (NSValueTransformer*)dataJSONTransformer{
    return [MTLValueTransformer mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:[GIData class]];
}

@end


@implementation GITideSummary

+ (NSDictionary*)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey{
    return @{@"tides" : @"tideSummary"};
}

+ (NSValueTransformer*)tidesJSONTransformer{
    return [MTLValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:[GITide class]];
}

@end

SpecBegin(MantleTestClass)

it(@"should initialize GITideSummary from JSON", ^{
    NSDictionary *values =
    @{
      @"tideSummary": @[@{
                            @"date": @{
                                    @"pretty": @"11:58 AM PST on December 19, 2013"
                                    },
                            @"utcdate": @{
                                    @"pretty": @"7:58 PM GMT on December 19, 2013",


                                    },
                            @"data": @{
                                    @"height": @"5.97 ft",
                                    @"type": @"High Tide"
                                    }
                            }]
      };

    NSError *error = nil;
    GITideSummary *summary = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[GITideSummary class]
                                       fromJSONDictionary:values
                                                    error:&error];

    expect(summary).to.beKindOf([GITideSummary class]);
    expect(summary.tides.count).to.equal(1);
    GITide *tide = summary.tides[0];
    expect(tide).to.beKindOf([GITide class]);
    expect(tide.data).to.beKindOf([GIData class]);
    expect(tide.data.height).to.equal(@"5.97 ft");
});

SpecEnd
```

Comment: I looked at that and JSONModel. Would it be able to work with an array with multiple objects. They would almost be submodels of the parent?

Comment: Yes, you can write your own transformers. For example: https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle/issues/155

Comment: Ah, that example has it using 1 object in that array. How would that work with accessing nested similar to the dataset I posted above?

Comment: w8 a second, i will try to write this and then i will submit the code

Comment: Going through this now! What does the ```GI``` prefix stand for?

Comment: it's nothing important. i just made it in my test project, which has class prefix GI.

Comment: Is the ```Spec``` the test for the code? And I would then be able to access this model by ```self.tideDate``` - or would I still have to initialize that binding to ```self```

Comment: I think the last bit im confused about (I can refer to the docs too) - accessing and using this data. I would create a new instance of that class and continue. So ```summary``` returns an array. Then I can always go and build more transformers to add in more values to display within my app

Comment: Debris, been playing around with your example. Would I be able to return 1 dictionary and include ```tideSummary`` as an array then add another say for the weather and keep chaining? ```@currentWeather: @"observation.temp_f"```

Comment: So my model at the end will contain more than an array of tideSummary, i want to then grab location, city, current temp, etc. All of which are keys inside of a dictionary not array. Does that work with Mantle?